# Conditional rendring on button click in functional componet in react js

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-hooks

I have one go now button, on click of button, check 3 conditions if conditions are true then redirect to another route or component

Comment: Do you use `react-router`?

Comment: What code you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
onClick={ ()=> {
      if (condition1 && condition2 && condition3) {
         this.setState({redirect : true}); // or setSomeVarible using useState
      }
   } 

}
```

In your render (do similar check in return if its a functional component)

```
  if (this.state.redirect) {
     return <Redirect to="/new-route" />
     // or return <NewComponent />
     // or window.location.href = 'https://whatever-url.com'
  }
```

Comment: There are 3 different conditions, I tried to use ternary operator and it is functional component